# C: Multiplying Two ScanFs

Tags: c

I have the following program:

```
   #include <stdio.h>

 int main (void)
{
int n, number, employeeNumber,counter;
float wage,hours,grossPay;
grossPay = wage*hours;

    for ( counter = 1; counter <=5; ++counter) {

    printf ("Enter Clock#:");
    scanf ("%i",&number);
    printf ("Enter Wage:");
    scanf ("%f",&wage);
    printf ("Enter Hours:");
    scanf ("%f",&hours);

    employeeNumber = 0;

    for ( n = 1; n <= number; ++n)
        employeeNumber +=n;

    printf ("--------------------------------\n");
    printf ("Clock#    Wage    Hours    Gross\n");
    printf ("--------------------------------\n");
    printf ("%06i     %.02f      %.01f   %f\n\n", number, wage, hours,grossPay);
    }
    return 0;        
    }
```

When I run the program, grossPay currently comes out to zero. I want grossPay to equal wage*hours, and it will depends on what I type in as the wage and hours for that clock number. Can anyone provide a tip on how to go about this? Thanks!

Comment: grossPay = wage*hours;  you are doing this before scanning the variables..

Comment: Please learn to code loops as for(i = 0; i < N; i++) instead of for(i=1; i<=N; ++i). It will make life easier for you later when you learn about arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move this line

```
grossPay = wage*hours;
```

after

```
scanf ("%f",&hours);
```

You should try to calculate `grossPay` after user inputs `wage` & `hours`. By default during declaration `wage` and `hours` will be initialized to default value i.e. `0.0` and hence you are getting `grossPay` zero.

Answer (score 0):

you are assigning grosspay to wage&hours before even assigning any value to wage and hours. Do it after the last scanf inside the first for loop.

Answer (score 0):

you are calculating it before giving information so try it

```
printf ("--------------------------------\n");

grossPay = wage*hours;

printf ("%06i     %.02f      %.01f   %f\n\n", number, wage, hours,grossPay);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this, than you don't required the line "grossPay = wage*hours;"

printf ("%06i     %.02f      %.01f   %f\n\n", number, wage, hours,wage*hours);

Comment: However that offers the same functionality that makes it harder to read/understand so I wouldn't do that